# How to prevent JQuery method .html() from changing case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, methods

I am creating a website, on which I also want to display some Java Code. I am using an AJAX request to get HTML content from the server. Then the content is inserted in a specifiv div element with the id content.

To insert the HTML content, which also contains the Java Code, I am using JQuery's `.html(htmlString)` method. However, the Java-Code is changed like this:

When there is a usage of generics in Java, JQuery thinks it's a tag! For whatever reason, the .html method suddenly changes all text in between `<` and `>` to lower case letters.

How do I avoid this behavior? Is there any parameter I can set to stop it from doing that? It shouldn't even do that, because first of all it's unexpected and second it doesn't matter if the characters are lower or upper case, browsers will still understand, probably because they are lower casing them themselves at some point internally.

**EDIT#1:**

.empty() and then .append() results in the same behavior.

**EDIT#2:**

There is the problem, that I do not only have `Java code` inside the result of the `AJAX response`, but also true `HTML content`, which would get escaped as well, if I use `escape()`.

**EDIT#3:**

One of the comments mentioned, that maybe I should refactor the AJAX response, so that text and HTML content are separated from each other. This sounds like a good idea in general and maybe I'll go with that.
I wonder however, if there is any method to set HTML content, which doesn't make the content go though unwanted changes.

Comment: You have to HTML-encode the content on server side

Answer (score 4):

You can just use jQuery's [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Added more information about my AJAX response content in the post. The `text()` method causes the html content to be escaped as well.

Comment: Sounds like your AJAX response needs to be refactored to return html strings, and text strings in different parts.

Comment: That sounds like an idea! I wonder if there is really no way to set html content without it going through unwanted change though : /

Answer (score 3):

Before using `.html(htmlString)` method, replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks
Anurag

Comment: It seems the html method is "too clever" and still interprets the generics as tags. the append method does the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the string using the escape() function. So

```
.html(escape(javaBlock));
```

Comment: escape() is deprecated, probably not a good idea. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: Added more information about my AJAX response content in the post. The escape() method causes the html content to be escaped as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `escape()` on the `htmlString`, specifically `.html(escape(htmlString))`. See [MDN for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape).

You can also use jQuery's [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method, which will do this for you automatically, such as `.text(htmlString)`.

Comment: thanks for the input, edited my post to be more specific about the content of the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `createTextNode()`function which will escape the special chars for you:

So this will do what you want:

```
escapedText = document.createTextNode(yourJavaCodeSnippetText)
$("#yourElementId").html(escapedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have an HTML entity conversion function, but you can roll your own. Example:

```
if(typeof escapeHtmlEntities == 'undefined') {
        escapeHtmlEntities = function (text) {
            return text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666<>\&]/g, function(c) {
                return '&' + 
                (escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable[c.charCodeAt(0)] || '#'+c.charCodeAt(0)) + ';';
            });
        };

        // all HTML4 entities as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
        escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable = {
            34 : 'quot', 
            38 : 'amp', 
            39 : 'apos', 
            60 : 'lt', 
            62 : 'gt', 
        };
}
```

Then call

```
.html(escapeHtmlEntities(javaBlock));
```